# Pulling image from Harbor registry takes long time and retries some layers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, harbor

Below is My environment.

```
Harbor helm version : 1.3.2
k8s : rancher 2.4.2 rke cluster
nginx(tls termination) - ingress - harbor
```

It takes only few seconds when pushing images to harbor, but when pulling images from harbor, some layers are pended and retry while other layers are downloaded speedy.
After first retrying, pended layers are downloaded speedy like other layers.

On harbor-core pod, some errors like below are logged that time

```
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] Handler crashed with error net/http: abort Handler
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go:309
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/registryproxy/handler.go:60
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/countquota/handler.go:55
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/immutable/handler.go:55
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/sizequota/handler.go:55
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/vulnerable/handler.go:46
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/contenttrust/handler.go:45
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/listrepo/handler.go:90
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/multiplmanifest/handler.go:47
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/regtoken/handler.go:32
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/url/handler.go:73
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/readonly/hanlder.go:44
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/middlewares/inlet.go:56
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/core/controllers/proxy.go:22
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:447
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:308
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /harbor/src/vendor/github.com/astaxie/beego/router.go:853
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878
2020/04/28 05:47:16.774 [C] [panic.go:522] /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
```

This situation occurs usually when pulling image that has layers which is not exist on my machine yet.

Could you please help me?

Comment: It looks like you are using a pretty old version of Harbor. Some people have reported similar problems with it. Try upgrading to 1.4.0 as that error did not occur in that particular version of Harbor.

Comment: @OhHiMark dear Mark, 1.3.2 is not harbor version. It is helm chart version. With 1.3.2 helm, harbor v1.10.2 is deployed. thnx anyway.